# Hibernate OneToMany SELECT gives repeated column in mapping for entity

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, one-to-many, hibernate-onetomany

I need to make one to many relation between Society and BlockFloors Table. Error:
`Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.example.domain.SocietyBlockFloor column: society_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`

**SocietyDetails.java**

```
package com.example.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name="society_details")
public class SocietyDetails {
    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "society_id")
    private String societyId;

    @Column(name = "society_name")
    private String societyName;

    @Column (name = "society_address")
    private String societyAddress;

    @Column (name = "society_country_details_code")
    private String societyCountryDetailsCode;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "societyDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<SocietyBlockFloor> societyBlockFloor = new ArrayList<SocietyBlockFloor>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Society{" +
                "societyId='" + societyId + '\'' +
                ", societyName='" + societyName + '\'' +
                ", societyAddress='" + societyAddress + '\'' +
                ", societyCountryDetailsCode='" + societyCountryDetailsCode + '\'' +
                ", societyBlockFloor='" + societyBlockFloor + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public static long getSerialVersionUID() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

    public String getSocietyId() {
        return societyId;
    }

    public void setSocietyId(String societyId) {
        this.societyId = societyId;
    }

    public String getSocietyName() {
        return societyName;
    }

    public void setSocietyName(String societyName) {
        this.societyName = societyName;
    }

    public String getSocietyAddress() {
        return societyAddress;
    }

    public void setSocietyAddress(String societyAddress) {
        this.societyAddress = societyAddress;
    }

    public String getSocietyCountryDetailsCode() {
        return societyCountryDetailsCode;
    }

    public void setSocietyCountryDetailsCode(String societyCountryDetailsCode) {
        this.societyCountryDetailsCode = societyCountryDetailsCode;
    }

    public List<SocietyBlockFloor> getSocietyBlockFloor() {
        return societyBlockFloor;
    }

    public void setSocietyBlockFloor(List<SocietyBlockFloor> societyBlockFloor) {
        this.societyBlockFloor = societyBlockFloor;
    }
}
```

**SocietyBlockFloor.java**

```
package com.example.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name="society_block_floor")
public class SocietyBlockFloor implements Serializable {
    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="society_id")
    private String societyBlockFloorId;

    @Column(name="society_block")
    private String societyBlock;

    @Column(name="society_floor")
    private String societyFloor;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "society_id", nullable = false)
    private SocietyDetails societyDetails;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "HASocietyBlockFloor{" +
                "societyBlockFloorId='" + societyBlockFloorId + '\'' +
                ", societyBlock='" + societyBlock + '\'' +
                ", societyFloor='" + societyFloor + '\'' +
                ", societyDetails='" + societyDetails + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public String getSocietyBlockFloorId() {
        return societyBlockFloorId;
    }

    public String getSocietyBlock() {
        return societyBlock;
    }

    public void setSocietyBlock(String societyBlock) {
        this.societyBlock = societyBlock;
    }

    public String getSocietyFloor() {
        return societyFloor;
    }

    public void setSocietyFloor(String societyFloor) {
        this.societyFloor = societyFloor;
    }

    public SocietyDetails getSocietyDetails() {
        return societyDetails;
    }

    public void setSocietyDetails(SocietyDetails societyDetails) {
        this.societyDetails = societyDetails;
    }
}
```

**DAO Class**

```
package com.example.dao.impl;

@Repository
public class SocietyDetailsDAOImpl extends BaseDAOImpl implements SocietyDetailsDAO {
    @Override
    public List<SocietyDetails> getSocietyDetailsByName(String societyName) throws Exception {
        try {
            String queryString = "from SocietyDetails society JOIN society.societyBlockFloor where society.societyName=:societyName";
            Query query = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(queryString);
            query.setParameter("societyName", societyName);
            List<SocietyDetails> societyDetails = query.list();
            return societyDetails;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

I've already tried to change the name of SocietyBlockFloor.societyBlockFloorId, but then in the ON clause it still uses (society.societyId = societyBlockFloor.societyId) where societyBlockFloor.societyId doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

you have a repeated column in the mapping. You mapped the same database column twice. you have:

```java
@Id
@Column(name="society_id")
private String societyBlockFloorId;
```

And

```java
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "society_id", nullable = false)
private SocietyDetails societyDetails;
```

This seems useless

```
@Id
@Column(name="society_id")
private String societyBlockFloorId;
```

If you want societyid just ask to `societyDetails.getId();`

And this on the manyToOne side 
`referencedColumnName = "society_id"`

Comment: I've tried this but in the query ON clause, it still uses society_id. Also, as I want a list of block floors mapped to every society. Is it possible using Hibernate or the basic solution of mapping it inside a helper.java should be preferred?